# Spaces admitting each singleton as zero set

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking for classes of spaces $X$ having the property that for each $x_0 \in X$ there is a continuous map $f:X \to \mathbb R$ such that $Z(f) := f^{-1}(0) = \lbrace x_0\rbrace$. Examples are:

- Metric spaces with $f(x) = d(x,x_0)$
- Discrete spaces

Do you know of other classes of spaces with this property ?

Comment: Note that all discrete spaces are metric, so you really have only one class here.

Comment: What about [completely regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_regular_space) $T_1$-spaces?

Comment: @Martin: They don't all have the property: look at $\omega_1+1$ with the order topology, for instance. The property implies that every singleton is a $G_\delta$.

Comment: Perfectly normal Hausdorff spaces have this property, more or less by definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every submetrizable space has the desired property, where a space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is *submetrizable* iff there is a coarser metrizable topology $\tau'$ on $X$, i.e., a metrizable topology such that $\tau\supseteq\tau'$. More generally, if $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is any space with the property in question, and $\tau'\supseteq\tau$ is a finer topology on $X$, then $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ also has the property. The proof is trivial: every $\tau$-continuous $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is automatically $\tau'$-continuous. This provides an abundance of non-metrizable examples, many of which aren't even regular.

Answer (score 2):

If the space $X$ is completely regular and a point $x_0\in X$ is a $G_\delta$-point. then this point is a Zero set of $X$.this means that each completely regular space with the additional property that, every point of it is a $G_\delta$ is in the class you asked.